# kubernetes liveness port from environment

Tags: kubernetes

here there is my deployment

```
     ...
     envFrom:
     - configMapRef:
          name: myapp-cmap-l

     livenessProbe:
       httpGet:
         path: /
         port: ???
       initialDelaySeconds: 5
       periodSeconds: 5
     ...
```

*myapp-cmap-l* contains APP_PORT=5000.

How can I reference that value on readinessProbe? Tried ${APP_PORT} or $(APP_PORT)

Riccardo

Comment: time to use https://helm.sh/ ...

Comment: Can you confirm that on pure kubernetes deployment there is no way to achieve this?

Comment: the only use ive ever seen of `configMapKeyRef` was for the `env` section, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/ k8s is pretty well documented, if they didnt mention another option- i believe no such exists  ...

Comment: Is there any particular reason that port number needs to be configurable?  Remember that each pod gets its own IP address, so there shouldn't usually be port conflicts.  I'd just write "5000" in the pod spec everywhere you need it, and not put it in a ConfigMap.

Comment: It's just because when I develop on my machine I need to start two instances of this node-js application. Using APP_PORT I can easily manage them...

Comment: maybe the easiest solution is to add a APP_PORT default to 5000 in the code and avoiding to specify it on config map

Comment: @Riccardo79 definitelly yes, better put it in the code instead of configmap.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/mysql/templates/deployment.yaml#L180